# Jquery - Reading table data of Iframe of Different Domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Any idea, Page loaded from different domain in iframe containing a table in it. how can i get that table.. Using any language, html, javascript, jquery, php, etc ..

Comment: Can you give some exmple here? A fiddle? What have you tried?

Comment: Tried everything. Loaded that page into iframe, then when i want to get the content, i get the error that permission denied in firebug.. Is there any solution for this. i want to get the data of external webpage in my page. the data in that webpage is available only after i performed the submit action in that page, so i used iframe ..

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the "external webpage", if so you can change it to send the data back to parent page using javascript.

Comment: No.. I dont have control over that.. It is from different server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can get data after posting the form with PHP too. Try this:

```
$post = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $post
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

`$file` now contains the response to the posted data. Now parse it via simplehtmldom that i said below.

Obviously, it won't work due to the cross-origin policy restrictions.

If you know the `src` of the iframe, you can get the source by either `CURL` or `file_get_contents` and then read through the DOM structure to get the desired table data.

A sample code:

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'IFRAME_URL_HERE' );
```

Once you have got the source, you can parse it very easily by using a library called SimpleHTMLDom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It can get you the desired table data in like a line or two of code. (Very similar syntax to jQuery, just written in PHP).

If you can give the iframe src and which table data you want, i can give you a working sample.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the data in that webpage is available only after i performed the submit action in that page, so i used iframe , Bcoz of this file_get_contents wont work for me.. So how can i do this.

Comment: Ok, from what i understand, the link you gave is your page where you submit a number, which if correct, opens a link in iframe. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You could get it using CURL in PHP - just curl the url that the iframe is loading. Here's a simple guide to getting started doing this kind of thing (scraping with PHP).

http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/marc_plotz011410.php3

Comment: the data in that webpage is available only after i performed the submit action in that page, so i used iframe .. How can i achieve this

Comment: You can set options in curl (`curl_setopt`) to POST the data. There is even [a good Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775161/how-can-scrape-website-via-php-that-requires-post-data) about this.

Comment: You can perform submit action using CURL in PHP also. When an HTML form is submitted, it will send either and HTTP GET or POST request depending on the "method" attribute of the form. You can send the same request using CURL also.

Comment: Curl is doing the "submit" for you. When you click submit, some data is being POSTed to the url. You just have to capture that data (you can inspect it in Chrome's Devtools under the Network tab), store it in a PHP variable, and post that variable to the URL (as demonstrated in the Stack Overflow question I linked to).