# Scrape content with PHP from page loading content through AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I need to scrape contents from the following [site](http://badmintonpeople.dk/DBF/HoldTurnering/Stilling/#6,2014,,,,,,1625,) so I can get results for my sports team. 
The problem is, that the content on the page is loaded after the actual page load, so it's not possible just to use frameworks as `simple_html_dom` parser, because the data is not in the DOM when page is loaded.

Can anyone give a hint on how to get the data from that page although it is loaded about one second after page load?

The tricky part about this is, that the content seems to be loaded through an asmx service, which I can't seem to figure out how that works. It looks like it first gets the JavaScript functions to actually call the service, and afterwards it posts to the service, with some parameters to actually fetch the content.

I've tried this:

```
<?php
    $data1 = array ( 
        ageGroupID => "",
        callbackcontextkey => "AD660FACB92F5451B76F322F9284247F0044FCCE817DEE083B7B147100D853DEC61A0521423A76CD85C7B433DE4EB970",
        clubID => "1617",
        leagueGroupID => "",
        leagueGroupTeamID => "",
        leagueMatchID => "",
        playerID => "",
        regionID => "",
        seasonID => "2014",
        subPage => "6"
    );                                                                   

$data_string = json_encode($data1);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/GetLeagueStanding');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result; 

?>
```

And I get this response :

> {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: Either inspect the source code, find the ajax endpoint, call it directly and parse the response, or install phantomjs

Comment: Use your browser's network tab to determine the AJAX URI. You can then parse that directly as @user574632 says.

Comment: it looks like the content is loaded through an asmx service - but I can't seem to find out how to get that content :( can you maybe look into the page and give me a hint?

Comment: @Quentin, this is not a duplicate of the question marked!

Comment: @phpNoobish — What (aside from the specific site in question, because answers should address the general problem) is different about this question?

Comment: You might need cURL on this, since as you say it's a POST operation. The request body is (by default) `{"callbackcontextkey":"D28B521C56C675C07944578B64450DE5BF24E7D1A057CCCA4AE18394F5D8A83399B486BB36F074CA8AF7FDC491F2CDD2","subPage":"6","seasonID":"2014","leagueGroupID":"","ageGroupID":"","regionID":"","leagueGroupTeamID":"","leagueMatchID":"","clubID":"1625","playerID":""}` and the [URL is here](http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/GetLeagueStanding). That should be enough to get you started?

Comment: In terms of duplicates, I wonder if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8775161/472495) would be a better fit. The question contains a bit of code to fetch a POST page.

Comment: @halfer, I already tried cURL, but I was not getting any valid response no matter what I tried. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please edit in the example you've tried, into this question. Ping me and I'll see if it can be reopened.

Comment: See what headers your browser sends that presently you do not. I'd firstly try `User-Agent`, then maybe `Host`, and also `Accept`. I'll vote to reopen too.

Comment: Also, [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` should be `urlencode`d - try that also and independently.